# получить объект (функцию) require после перезаписи переменной

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, commonjs

```js
globalThis.require='test'; //перезаписываем глобально
var require = globalThis.require; //перезаписываем в области видимости
console.log(require) //выводит "test" => перезаписано
```

Как получить `require` обратно?

**О чём этот вопрос**:

Как получить саму функцию из `process` (пример) или иных `await import('node:?')` импортов в Deno функцию `require` и де-факто как получить её в самом Node.js.

Нужно, чтобы получить возможность использовать CommonJS в Deno и в целом, в случае перезаписи `require` в Node.js.

**При чём здесь пример?**

Если безвозвратно перезаписать, то откуда взять `require` (`import`)

Comment: `globalThis._require = require; globalThis.require='test'; ...`

Comment: Собственно, да... сохранить исходное значение в отдельной переменной. З.Ы. rollback в js нет

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо за подсказку о сохранении, но вопрос про возможность вернуть `require` в Deno. В Deno можно в top-level сделать `await import('node:process')`. Однако, интерес не только по вопросу `require` в Deno, а в целом.

Comment: ну, вернуть её, естественно, можно присвоив сохраненное значение `globalThis.require = globalThis._require`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в целом: https://codeberg.org/slnknrr/1.41.1d4pr-js-l-node.polyfil.nodejs7386

Решение этого вопроса:

```
(await import('node:module')).createRequire(import.meta.url)
```

^ создаёт `require` для CommonJS